# Entry point for procedure not found with SDL_JoystickRumble()

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I was going to try out the new SDL_JoystickRumble() feature in SDL 2.0.9 and added the line:
SDL_JoystickRumble(gamepad1, 20, 20, 1000);
to the code, to get a PS4 controller that i already had verified that worked with my program to rumble for 1 second.

Running it gave me the exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x776EE01E (ntdll.dll) in Win32Project2.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.

and a pop-up saying:

> SDL_JoystickRumble entry point for procedure not found in library for dynamic linkers

However, when i tried deleting the SDL_JoystickRumble(gamepad1, 20, 20, 1000); line that caused the exception, i still got it, with the same pop up. does anyone know why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Comment: You probably use older version of `SDL2.dll` (either in your executable's directory or in `system32` or `syswow64` system directory) that don't have said function.

Comment: i tried re-downloading SDL 2.0.9 and replace SDL2.dll in my directory, and even double checked that VC++ used the correct library directory, but the problem is still there

Comment: But you don't know if it is being used or just silently skipped because of incompatibility or missing dependencies. At least remove other `SDL2.dll` in system [library lookup directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) (better solution is tracing your program loading presumably correct file, with e.g. procmon - but it is a bit more advanced debugging).

Comment: I recommend [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to diagnose DLL loading issues.

Comment: Thank you keltar, it apparently loaded the dll from somewhere else, just like you said. so after going around and replacing some old dlls at some other directories with the new one i finally got it to work again